# Why is my XSLT style sheet not pulling values from my XML file for a table?

Tags: xml, xslt

To be honest this is my first XML project, but I've finally grown tired of looking up the answer on my own. I'm trying to create an address book, having the contacts data saved in an XML file and pulled from the transformed XSLT style sheet to produce a simple table. Here's a copy of my files, help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="contactdata.xsl"?>

<!DOCTYPE addressbook [
<!ELEMENT addressbook (contact)>
<!ELEMENT contact (fname,lname,mi,staddress,city,state,zip,phone,email,twitter)>
<!ELEMENT fname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT mi (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT staddress (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT state (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT zip (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT phone (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT email (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT twitter (#PCDATA)>
]>

<addressbook>
<contact>
<fname>Peyton</fname>
<lname>Manning</lname>
<mi>Z</mi>
<staddress>123 Go Vols</staddress>
<city>Denver</city>
<state>CO</state>
<zip>12345</zip>
<phone>1-800-youwish</phone>
<email>pmanning@broncos.com</email>
<twitter>peyton_manning</twitter>
</contact>

<contact>
<fname>Eric</fname>
<lname>Berry</lname>
<mi>P</mi>
<staddress>123 Arrowhead Stadium</staddress>
<city>Kansas City</city>
<state>MO</state>
<zip>34567</zip>
<phone>816-213-4452</phone>
<email>eberry@chiefs.com</email>
<twitter>eric_berry</twitter>
</contact>
</addressbook>
```

and my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="sitetemplate.css"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Middle Initial</th>
<th>Street Address</th>
<th>City</th>
<th>State</th>
<th>Zip</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Twitter</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="addressbook/contact">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="fname"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="lname"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="mi"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="staddress"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="city"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="state"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="zip"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="phone"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="email"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="twitter"/></td>

      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also I'd like to mention that as of how the code is written now that my first row is produced, but my table just stops afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to mention that as of how the code is written now that my
>   first row is produced, but my table just stops afterwards

No. the provided transformation works OK and produces one `tr` for each `contact` element -- as intended

**However the wanted transformation can be expressed in a much shorter way**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Middle Initial</th>
                    <th>Street Address</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>Zip</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Twitter</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="contact">
  <tr><xsl:apply-templates/></tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="contact/*">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<addressbook>
    <contact>
        <fname>Peyton</fname>
        <lname>Manning</lname>
        <mi>Z</mi>
        <staddress>123 Go Vols</staddress>
        <city>Denver</city>
        <state>CO</state>
        <zip>12345</zip>
        <phone>1-800-youwish</phone>
        <email>pmanning@broncos.com</email>
        <twitter>peyton_manning</twitter>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <fname>Eric</fname>
        <lname>Berry</lname>
        <mi>P</mi>
        <staddress>123 Arrowhead Stadium</staddress>
        <city>Kansas City</city>
        <state>MO</state>
        <zip>34567</zip>
        <phone>816-213-4452</phone>
        <email>eberry@chiefs.com</email>
        <twitter>eric_berry</twitter>
    </contact>
</addressbook>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Middle Initial</th>
            <th>Street Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Zip</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Twitter</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Peyton</td>
            <td>Manning</td>
            <td>Z</td>
            <td>123 Go Vols</td>
            <td>Denver</td>
            <td>CO</td>
            <td>12345</td>
            <td>1-800-youwish</td>
            <td>pmanning@broncos.com</td>
            <td>peyton_manning</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Eric</td>
            <td>Berry</td>
            <td>P</td>
            <td>123 Arrowhead Stadium</td>
            <td>Kansas City</td>
            <td>MO</td>
            <td>34567</td>
            <td>816-213-4452</td>
            <td>eberry@chiefs.com</td>
            <td>eric_berry</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of templates, pattern matching and the XSLT processing model.

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet works fine for me.

It's a little more standard form in xsl to use recursive template matching rather than `<xsl:for-each>` when you can easily do it.  And in this case, it's quite simple.

With that style your template would be changed to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="addressbook">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Middle Initial</th>
      <th>Street Address</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>Zip</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Twitter</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </table>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="contact">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="fname"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="lname"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="mi"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="staddress"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="city"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="state"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="zip"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="phone"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="email"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="twitter"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For a simple table of course either works.  But it's worth learning this style as it can be much better for more complex structures.